# Unable to resolve service for type 'Domain.IBlobModelCache' while attempting to activate 'Domain.EntityMaterializerSource'

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Although the error message seems obvious I believe it is different from other questions. As you can see in my `Startup` I have registered `IBlobModelCache` service.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    ...
    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options
                .ReplaceService<IEntityMaterializerSource, Domain.EntityMaterializerSource>();
                .UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"),
                    opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly("API")
                    );
        });

        services
            .AddAuthentication(ConfigureAthentication)
            .AddJwtBearer(ConfigureJwtBearer);

        services
            .AddLogging(ConfigureLogging)
            .AddTransient<IBlobPersisterFactory, BlobPersisterFactory>()
            .AddTransient<IBlobDbContextSavingHandler, BlobDbContextSavingHandler>()
            .AddTransient<IBlobDbContextModelCreator, BlobDbContextModelCreator>()
            .AddSingleton<IBlobModelCache, BlobModelCache>() // It is here
            .AddOptions<DiskBlobStorageSettings>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, config) => config.Bind("BlobStorage", settings));

    }
    ...
}
```

And here the constructor of my services so you can see that there is not any loop in them.

```cs
class EntityMaterializerSource : Base.EntityMaterializerSource
{
    public EntityMaterializerSource(
        [NotNull] EntityMaterializerSourceDependencies dependencies,
        IBlobModelCache blobModelCache
        )
        : base(dependencies)
    {
        BlobModelCache = blobModelCache;
        OnMaterializedMethod = typeof(EntityMaterializerSource)
            .GetMethod(nameof(OnMaterialized), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    }

}

class BlobModelCache : IBlobModelCache
{
    // Has no constructor
}
```

The `BlobModelCache` is resolved in other services successfully and the error only happens when EF needs to materialize entities.

All I need is to be notified when an entity is materialized from DB and I could not find any solution but extending EntityMaterializerSource. I am using EF Core 3.1.8 and ASP.Net Core 3.1.